# Descending order ZoneDateTime in list kotlin

Tags: kotlin, date, datetime, time, zoneddatetime

I have list of ZoneDateTime. I want to order by descending order. I didn't find the solution. Can some one guide me.

```
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T20:09:03+01:00, event=xyz)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T09:15:15+01:00, event=abc)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T23:15:15+01:00, event=qwe)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T14:00:40+01:00, event=aks)
```

**NearestResult.kt**

```
data class NearestResult(
    val day: ZonedDateTime,
    val event: String
)
```

I tried some code but it's not working

```
lis.groupBy { it.day }
```

It giving me same above order.

**Expected Output**

```
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T23:15:15+01:00, event=qwe)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T20:09:03+01:00, event=xyz)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T14:00:40+01:00, event=aks)
NearestResult(day=2020-05-09T09:15:15+01:00, event=abc)
```

Can somone guide me. Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Vivek, long time no see ;) try `list.sortByDescending { it.day }` this will mutate your list and sort it as you expect. [Here's a playground](https://pl.kotl.in/rOqGS1thX) sorting it ;)

Comment: Hi Martin, I tag you so many times but I didn't know what happened after.

Comment: Took a bit of a break, but I hang out [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help) (but only sometimes, I'm less active around here). Glad to hear you fixed your sorting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
val desc = compareByDescending<NearestResult>{
   it.day
}
val asc = compareBy<NearestResult>{
   it.day
}
   
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(desc)
println(sortedList)

//or

list.sortedByDescending{ it.day }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.sortedBy { it.day }.reversed()
```